# in mysql database, all rows have disappeared in all tables during the same time. what has caused the disappearing?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have faced a serious problem. I have a mysql database having many tables. The records entered(rows) in all those tables from 6th up to 9th Dec 2016 have disappeared. I have checked to see if someone would have deleted anything from those tables but I did not found any sign or any thing that should have caused that mysterious delete. I have also checked in phpmyadmin as I'm using wampserver to check if maybe records are there and not being displayed on the system interface but there are not there. I have checked in my dairy backup and found all missing records, but unfortunately, the backup of 9th Dec 2016 was not successful. I wonder how to bring back my data and how to avoid that situation once and for all. Thank you!

Comment: You cannot recover deleted data from mysql. If you have a backup you can use it, but for the other records you cannot do nothing. Make the backup crontab each day or every 12 hours

Comment: It seems that you or somebody else have restored the backup of Dec 5th on your database!